# Overflow-x position on right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one paragraph `p` where I need to display some data.

I set `white-space:nowrap` and `text-align:right`. When someone types some content in one text field, this content shows in the paragraph from right to left.

But when data comes to left `scroll-x` was set to `left`, and to see new typed content you need to scroll to right.

I need the reverse, showing new content and scroll if you want to see the old one.

If i use direction: rtl, it works fine, but only for word, not with number, so i need another solution. Ofc i have an idea to do this with javascript, but i want solution without it.

```js
document.querySelector('#inpt').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = e.target.value
})
```

```css
p {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<input id="inpt" type="text">
<p id='display'>
</p>
```

Comment: `direction: rtl` worked for me for numbers as well, can you verify that it doesn't work?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JtnuXQR.png

Comment: Oh now I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `display: flex` with a `flex-direction` of `row-reverse` on your `p` tag seems to do the trick:

```js
document.querySelector('#inpt').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = e.target.value
})
```

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<input id="inpt" type="text">
<p id='display'>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes. that's it. Thank you. I knew that it must exist some no JS solution. :)

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: @Amessihel I knew :D ... But i just wrote this code for test here. In real app, code is more complex so i need to simplify it. But thanks for advice ofc :)